# How to disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth plugin for Magento Cloud Docker?

Tags: magento2.4, docker, cloud-docker

I am doing the Magento Cloud Docker setup in my Ubuntu server, however I need to bypass the 2 factor authentication because I am setup in local. I know that we can disable the related module for the normal setup, but how to do it with Magento Cloud Docker? I keep seeing `Autoload error: We can't read some files that are required to run the Magento application. This usually means file permissions are set incorrectly.` when I run `module:disable`. Can anyone guide me on what I miss here? I am attaching the screenshot of the error message and the ownership of the files and directories here.[image]

Comment: have you tried composer install

Comment: Sorry @rana, can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: please check my updated, if anything more requires please ask

Comment: The files user is `www-data`. Try adding yourself to that group `sudo usermod -aG www-data user`

Comment: hi @s-murtadha, I have tried that and run the module disable again but still the same, anything else I can do here?